# LinkTo returns an IDisposable to do the unlink - is this appropriate design?

Tags: task-parallel-library, api-design, tpl-dataflow

Why does `ISourceBlock<TOutput>.LinkTo` return an IDisposable with which you can unlink the link?

It doesn't seem an appropriate use of the IDisposable interface, and I can't think of any reason you'd want to write a using statement that would specifically require IDisposable, such as:

```
using (var unlinkHandle = Foo.LinkTo(Bar)) {

   // run some data items through the flow

} // compiler unlinks Bar from Foo here by calling unlinkHandle.Dispose()
```

IDisposable, of course, signals a resource that must be deterministically cleaned up and it is typically an error (or at least a flaw) not to call Dispose on an instance that implements IDisposable; that's not the case here. The use of IDisposable in this API, rather than a bespoke interface type, seems "cute" and/or lazy.

Am I correct…or missing something?

(Wouldn't it have been nicer if `ISourceBlock<TOutput>.LinkTo` returned its argument, so you could write a chain like `Foo.LinkTo(Bar).LinkTo(Zed)`?  There could have been a different (extension) method to do the unlink of Bar from Foo.)

Comment: Any reason you can't write an extension method to allow chaining?  (Although it seems ambiguous in your example if Zed is linking to Foo or Bar.)

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Yes I can write that extension method.  I'm curious why this method was designed this way.  (BTW, If I wanted Zed to link to Foo I would have written Foo.LinkTo(Bar, Zed) and had my hypothetical projected extension method take a params ITargetBlock[] argument.  Alternatively, I could have Foo.LinkTo(Bar).AndTo(Zed) ... etc. etc. for some fluid API design.)

Comment: I would imagine, and this is my own personal experience, is that beyond the idea of have a fluid design, most, if not all methods, fall into the same sort of [The problem with Lambda's ForEach()](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

Comment: @ErikPhilips - That's a good post to keep in mind, thanks!  But, rather than really being interested in the possiblity of a fluid API I'm actually trying to focus, in this question, on why this method returns IDisposable rather than some custom interface type with a single Unlink() method.  It disturbs me that IDisposable was re-used for this seemingly unrelated purpose ... unless there's a reason for it I don't see.

Comment: No worries, that is why I am making comments and not answers.